# Are there any prophesies in Old Testament which got fulfilled in Jesus, but of which one cannot find a mention in New Testament?

Tags: life-of-jesus, old-testament, new-testament, prophecy

It is said that there are more than 350 prophesies in the Old Testament which got fulfilled in Jesus and of which parallel reference can be found in New Testament. But the Evangelists have not given a cross reference to Old Testament in all such events which actually fulfilled Old Testament prophesies on Jesus.

My question is: **Are there any prophesies in Old Testament which indeed got fulfilled in Jesus, but one cannot find a mention  of such fulfilment in New Testament. For instance, was the cursing of Fig Tree by Jesus prophesied in Old Testament?**

Comment: Well, in the case of a number of prophesies, the Evangelists themselves mention that Jesus by doing such and such things fulfilled such and such prophesies. But the other events, like his burial in a prize tomb belonging to a rich man are only given a passing mention. But the reader is able to connect them to something in the OT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many writings in the Old Testament which got fulfilled in Jesus. One for instance,  is Isa 53:9 which says :

> They made his grave with the wicked
> and his tomb with the rich

And we have in Matt 27: 57-60 :

> As evening approached, there came a rich man from Arimathea, named Joseph, who had himself become a disciple of Jesus.  ..............  Joseph took the body, wrapped it in a clean linen cloth,  and placed it in his own new tomb that he had cut out of the rock

...and in John 19: 41-42 :

> At the place where Jesus was crucified, there was a garden, and in the garden a new tomb, in which no one had ever been laid.  Because it was the Jewish day of Preparation and since the tomb was nearby, they laid Jesus there.

So, we see that the tomb in which Jesus was buried, was  close to Calvary, and belonged to a rich man who could afford to build a tomb carved into rock. Had there been a choice, the disciples would have buried  Jesus far from Calvary where the condemned ones  met their death.

Thus, Jesus by  his burial in the rich man's tomb, fulfilled the prophesy of Isaiah. But no mention of the fulfilment is made in the Gospels.